# How to return MySQL table entries by specified value ASP.net/C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I know its probably something simple but its been driving me nuts for 2 days now

In short, what I want to do is return all of the entries from a specific table based on a value fed into the sql string from a label that holds the appropriate value

This is what I have currently, and it works, but I don't want it to be hardcoded to 'admin':

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE fromuser = 'admin'";
```

The above returns the entries in the table where the fromuser value is 'admin'

Like I said it works fine. What I want to do is something more like this:

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE fromuser = " + lblUsername.Text;
```

Where the lblUsername.Text is the value of the currently logged in user (in this case its admin just like before)

So my question is how to I feed the label value into the sql string so that I don't need to hardcode it as 'admin' so that what is returned changes with the value of lblUsername.Text?

Comment: Retrieve current user (google that, plenty of examples) then wherever that sql call is made use a param consistent with how other param are used in your application/framework that holds the value needed, ie the username. No single step is overly difficult, but you have given no info as to how this sql statement is created and used, no detail as to the user system your using, no referance to anything more specific so cant get more specific answer than that, but tbh it is all you need, just know general approach and google each step, you will a lot more in the process as well

Answer (score 0):

I think your first issue is you are missing the quotes when you are building the sql. So your query should look like

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE fromuser = '" + lblUsername.Text + "'";
```

But the that would be a horrible query to run against your database, because you would be very vulnerable for [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try parameterized query instead. 
I'm assuming your connection string is set in connectionString variable

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();    
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE fromuser = @fromUser", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("fromUser", lblUsername.Text)); 
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dataReader.HasRows){
//do all your reading.
}
connection.Close();
```

Also, I would suggest you to look into [Dapper dot net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), which is an excellent ORM to use rather than this naive ADO.NET code

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var textInLabel = lblUsername.Text;
        sqlString = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE fromuser ='" + textInLabel  + " '";
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE fromuser = '"+ lblUsername.Text+"'";
```